# Write Code that does the same like Numpy's reshape

Tags: multidimensional-array, numpy, python-3.x

I have to rewrite some Python Code, so that it is compatible with Python 3. Unfortunately one of my files imports Numpy, which isn't available for Python 3, yet. So I am trying to replace the Numpy-Code with normal Python Code. But I fail to replace Numpy's reshape-function.
Reshape takes an array as input and reshapes it (changes number of rows/columns). For example:

```
a = arange(10).reshape(2,5)
```

creates an array of the form

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
  5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

My idea was code like this:

```
list = range(10)
matrix = []
row = []
for i in range(2):
    for j in range 5:
        row.append(list[j])
    matrix.append(row)
    row = []
```

But nested loops don't look very nice. Do you know a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numpy FAQs says that it does not support python 3, but according to the following it does:

http://onpython3yet.com/packages/requirements?r=numpy%0D%0A

You might want to just check to see if your assumption about numpy's status is correct.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this great page. It is available, indeed!

Comment: It seems there's more than one set of FAQs. [These FAQs](http://www.scipy.org/FAQ#head-288204f886c0a120754d189f434864554a4a970d) correctly say it supports Python 3, while [these FAQs](http://new.scipy.org/faq.html#python-version-support) are out of date.

Answer (score 1):

for the Non-numpy option (numpy can be a daunting dependency):

```
x = range(10)
mat_2x5 = [x[i*5:(i+1)*5] for i in range(2)]
```

Comment: Thank you for this alternative :)